# Linkedin company name

Tags: linkedin

I worked for a company through an outsource company, but I have nearly no relation with the outsourcing company except they paid the salary. It was all done on a contract basis so I was never employee of the outsourcing company.
In my linkedin profile I put I worked for the company that actually I was doing the work for and now the outsourcing company demands I'll update that I worked for them.
Can they ask me to do so?

Comment: `Can they ask me to do so?` - Anyone can ask anyone to do anything. Do you mean in a legal sense?

Comment: An example of mine that would date from the mid 1990s would be worded as follows: 'Work on TPIPT project at Brooks AFB as member of CSC support organization as a Manpower temp'.  My programming project was for the Air Force, CSC was the government contractor, and they in turn had hired me through Manpower.  Such 'chain of custody' is common these days, many fingers are in the pie.

Comment: @AdamRabinovitch - Your Linkedin profile is your property just like your resume is your property.  They can ask and you can tell them to quickly kiss your shinny metal...well you get the point.  That is exactly what I would say to anyone that demanded I update my work history.

Answer (score 4):

They can *ask*. They cannot *demand*.

But it is **your** profile that you created to show **your** work.

It is completely up to you - you can give them a mention if you think they deserve it - how prominent or not is also up to you (a short - outsourced via companyname, for example).

Personally, I have had many jobs through recruiters/umbrella companies and such and most of these I have never mentioned in LinkedIn or my CV - they are not relevant to showing my career.

In short - up to you what you do here. They have no legal basis to force you to do this.

Comment: Just make sure that what you write is factually correct. You worked at/for company C but was not employed by them. The same could be said for the outsourcing company O.

Comment: @JanDoggen in Linkedin you need to choose a company name. I can elaborate around that. The reason I didn't put the outsource company name is because I had nearly no interaction with them, so I didn't see the point to make it too complicated and mention them.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I don't want to post here the email I received, but they kind of demanded it and said there is something in the contract. I got the email from the recruitment agency a few weeks after I left. The thing I've had nearly no interaction at all with the outsourcing company besides they paid me when I issued my agency the invoice.

Comment: @AdamRabinovitch: Sounds like you need to re-read the contract.

Comment: @AdamRabinovitch - If the contract is over. I am not sure what grounds they have. If it is in the contract then perhaps you should update it. In the end I would depending on the length of the contract, just remove it from my work history entirely, no sense in keeping negavity ( this type of behavior from them is negavity ).

Answer (score 0):

If your contract doesn't mention anything about such social media postings, you may not be at legal risk.

Although it may sound fancy to list that company (since you are doing it, am assuming its a big name), if I were you, I will honor the outsourcing company's request. For all you know its in the outsourcing company's contract with the company you are listing.
I had no hand in acquiring the client. I simply worked for the outsourcing firm and they paid me for it. It is only right to do so, as you really were engaged by the outsourcing firm. 
If a future employer asked you for a proof of employment with the company you mentioned in your linkedin profile, you will only be cutting sorry pictures and explaining that you never *really* worked for the company you listed on your linkedin profile. It just puts you in a not so positive light with the future employer.

Comment: If I'm a contractor I wasn't employed, but worked and issued an invoice and the outsourcing company paid me. 
I'm actually still shocked they asked to change it. I'm pretty much sure it's the outsourcing company and not the actual company.